# nodejs server doesn't receive response from the client

Tags: node.js, tcp, tcpserver

I'm new in nodeJS. I have a server that receives a command from a client. It sends to the server a command named "TIME". Then the server have to send to the client the current timestamp. Once the client have received the timestamp from the server, the first one sends another command.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I receive the "TIME" command but when the server sends to the client the current timestamp , it doesn't receive response from the client. It could be a client problem. I would like to know if the code writed below is correct.

```
var net = require("net");

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        var tmp = data.toString('utf8');
        var d = new Date();
        if (tmp.substr(0, 4) == "TIME"){
           console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));
           var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
           socket.write(ts.toString() + "\n");
        }else if (tmp.substr(19, 3)== "PW:"){
            console.log("PW packet received with UID="+tmp.substr(6, 18)+" and len="+tmp.substr(22, 27));
            socket.write("ODEOK\n\r");
        }else if (tmp.substr(19, 3)== "ST:"){
            console.log("ST packet received with UID="+tmp.substr(6, 18)+" and len="+tmp.substr(22, 27));
            socket.write("ODEOK\n\r");
        }else{
            console.log("Unknown data:"+ data);
            socket.write("ODERR\n\r");
        }

    });
    socket.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +' '+ socket.remotePort);
    });
    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });}).listen(1730);
```

I tested it with python and it works. I don't know why.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import time 

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1730))
s.listen(10)

while True:
  sc, addr = s.accept()

  data = sc.recv(1024)
  if data[0:4] == "TIME":
    print "TIME command received"
    sc.send(str(int(time.time()))+"\n")
  elif data[19:22] == "PW:":
    print "PW packet received with UID="+data[6:18]+" and len="+data[22:27]
    sc.send("ODEOK\n")
  elif data[19:22] == "SG:":
    print "SG packet received with UID="+data[6:18]+" and len="+data[22:27]
    sc.send("ODEOK\n")
  elif data[19:22] == "ST:":
    print "ST packet received with UID="+data[6:18]+" and len="+data[22:27]
    sc.send("ODEOK\n")
  else:
    print "Unknown data:", data
    sc.send("ODERR\n")

  sc.close()

s.close()
```

Comment: calling `end()` on the socket would send a FIN packet, which the client might be waiting for. can you share the code for the client?

Comment: You are right! The client was waiting the FIN packet. This is solved calling socket.end(). Thanks a lot!